# Python: 'object has no attribute ' (pyTsetlinMachine)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was wondering if I could solve the problem described at https://github.com/cair/pyTsetlinMachine/issues/6 "myself".

I added a running example to the github issue.

The following error occurs

```
File "/mnt/c/ProjectsGit/BreastCancerDemo_pkl.py", line 42, in <module>
    tm2.set_state(state)
  File "/home/unix/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyTsetlinMachine/tm.py", line 351, in set_state
    for i in range(self.number_of_classes):
AttributeError: 'MultiClassTsetlinMachine' object has no attribute 'number_of_classes'
```

The class 'MultiClassTsetlinMachine' seems to have such as attribute?
https://github.com/cair/pyTsetlinMachine/blob/0c1ff1d43e1dd466ae0e41d50a4bde94bb36fedc/pyTsetlinMachine/tm.py#L396

Is it the case that the attribute 'number_of_classes' is not stored? but could be recovered by the dimension of the vector?

Any ideas? Hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the source code that [the attribute gets set](https://github.com/cair/pyTsetlinMachine/blob/0c1ff1d43e1dd466ae0e41d50a4bde94bb36fedc/pyTsetlinMachine/tm.py#L195) (the first time) you run `fit`, and *does not* get stored or retrieved in `get_state` or `set_state`.  The code in that link is `self.number_of_classes = int(np.max(Y) + 1)`, so I guess `Y` is supposed to be numerically encoded and one-dimensional.  So yes, setting it yourself (not the dimension of the vector, but the number of unique values) should be enough.  You could pickle that number together with the state, if that's more convenient.

That should at least be a good start, but I'm not familiar enough with the package to know if everything will work correctly from there.